# Webcam microphone not working on multiple school computers

Tags: 20.04, webcam, microphone

I am currently helping my father-in-law with his Ubuntu machines. He owns a private primary school and has recently decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu. (YAY!)
With this pandemic situation, the school currently runs a hybrid between physical and Zoom-oriented education. Due to this, every classroom is now outfitted with webcams with built-in microphones so that the teachers can freely walk around and not be tied to the desk by a conventional microphone with a wire.

However, on some of the machines (not all), the microphone isn't working. The camera works fine, but Zoom doesn't detect any sound coming in. It is important to note that the microphones connected in the microphone jack on the front and back works fine. It is only the webcam's microphone that is connected through a USB that isn't working.

We would really appreciate some guidance as we are both fairly new to Ubuntu.

**OS: Ubuntu 20.04.02**

Please let me know if there are any terminal commands i should write to give you the information that you require.

**EDIT:**

> pacmd list-sources

```
   3 source(s) available.
    * index: 0
    name: <alsa_input.usb-WCM_USB_WEB_CAM-02.multichannel-input>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9040
    volume: mono: 51401 / 78% / -6,33 dB
    balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 16000Hz
    channel map: mono
    Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-WCM_USB_WEB_CAM-02>
    module: 7
    properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "USB Audio"
    alsa.id = "USB Audio"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "WEB CAM"
    alsa.long_card_name = "WCM_USB WEB CAM at usb-0000:00:12.2-3, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:3:1.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-WCM_USB_WEB_CAM-02"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "1c3f"
    device.vendor.name = "WCM_USB"
    device.product.id = "2002"
    device.product.name = "WEB CAM"
    device.serial = "WCM_USB_WEB_CAM"
    device.form_factor = "webcam"
    device.string = "hw:1"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "64000"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "32000"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "multichannel-input"
    device.profile.description = "Multicanal"
    device.description = "WEB CAM Multicanal"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
    multichannel-input: Entrada multicanal (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
    properties:
    
    active port: <multichannel-input>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB, front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
    Estéreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 1999,82 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of Áudio interno Estéreo analógico"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb40000 irq 16"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "1022"
    device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
    device.product.id = "780d"
    device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 30420 / 46% / -20,00 dB, front-right: 30420 / 46% / -20,00 dB
    balance 0,00
    base volume: 5841 / 9% / -63,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
    Estéreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 1999,82 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "ALC662 rev1 Analog"
    alsa.id = "ALC662 rev1 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb40000 irq 16"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "1022"
    device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
    device.product.id = "780d"
    device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:0"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Estéreo analógico"
    device.description = "Áudio interno Estéreo analógico"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
    analog-input-front-mic: Microfone frontal (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
    properties:
    device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-rear-mic: Microfone traseiro (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
    device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-linein: Entrada de linha (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
    
    active port: <analog-input-front-mic>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is will be useful info if you add the brand and model of usb cam or the output of: `lsusb` . Also have you tried cam microphone as input for other audio tool other than Zoom, Audacity for example ? Objective is to know the level of the issue, device-driver-alsa-(pulseaudio)-zoom